# JComboBox doesn't use string representation of object in Jython 2.1

Tags: java, swing, jython

I have a dialog written in Jython that uses JComboBoxes with objects. This works fine in Jython 2.5, but not in Jython 2.1 which I also need to support.

The class looks roughly like the following:

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self, item):
        self.key = item["key"]
        self.name = item["name"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

    def toString(self):
        return self.name

    def safeRepr(self):
        return self.name
```

I tried implementing every method that I could think of that converts the object to a string, but in Jython 2.1 I still get something like `org.python.core.PyInstance@1a2b3c` instead of the string representation in the JComboBox.

If I print the object to the console, it works fine and prints the representation I defined.

Any idea what the problem could be and how I can work around it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Jython 2.1 around, but on 2.2 you can work around the problem by deriving `Item` from `java.lang.Object` and overriding `toString()` like this:

```
from javax.swing import JComboBox, JFrame, JPanel, WindowConstants
from java.lang import Object

class Item(Object):
    def __init__(self, item):
        self.key = item["key"]
        self.name = item["name"]

    def toString(self):
        return self.name

frame = JFrame("JComboBox using Jython objects")
frame.setSize(150, 150)

item1 = {'key': 'item1', 'name': 'First item'}
item2 = {'key': 'item2', 'name': 'Second item'}
combo_box = JComboBox([Item(item1), Item(item2)])

panel = JPanel()
panel.add(combo_box)
frame.add(panel)
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)
frame.setVisible(True)
```